# Fetch List of User Ids From Nested Collection in Firestore Database using TypeScript (NestJs)

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, nest, tfs-query

I am working on firestore and my firestore collection structure as below:

**Users-> userId1 -> UserDetails -> User_Info -> JSON Data**

**Users-> userId2 -> UserDetails -> User_Info -> JSON Data**

**Users-> userId3 -> UserDetails -> User_Info -> JSON Data**

**Users-> userId4 -> UserDetails -> User_Info -> JSON Data**

For better understanding, please have a look in below snapshot:

[image]

Now I need a firestore query to fetch the list of userIds who has `isCardOrdered` is `true`.

The result should be:

```
[
"userId1",
"userId2",
"userId3",
"userId4"
]
```

I am doing this, but I am not getting the correct result.

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersClient {
    constructor(
        @Inject(UsersClientDocument.collectionName)
        private UsersCollection: CollectionReference<UsersClientDocument>,
    ) { }
   
   
   
        async fetchByQuery(query) {
            console.log('******************************');
            const querySnapshot = await this.UsersCollection.where('cardInfo[0].isCardOrdered', '==', true).get();
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(' **********fetchByQuery:',doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
        });
    }
    
    
}
```

And I am calling this method like this:

```
    const fireBaseUser: any = await this.UsersClient.fetchByQuery();
    console.log('fireBaseUser:',fireBaseUser);
```

**Request: Any help would be appreciated. Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `cardInfo` is an array, and Firestore doesn't support querying an item in an array in the way that you are trying here:

```
this.UsersCollection.where('cardInfo[0].isCardOrdered', '==', true).
```

Is you want to allow this query, you'll have to (also) store that value in a field that Firestore **can** query. For example, if you add an additional top-level field `isCardZeroOrdered`, you could query on that:

```
this.UsersCollection.where('isCardZeroOrdered', '==', true).
```

You could also store the info in a **map** field, rather than an array, which would visually look very similar, but would then allow you to query with:

```
this.UsersCollection.where('cardInfo.zero.isCardOrdered', '==', true).
```

Comment: Thanks, @Frank, I tried the same but it's not working.

Comment: "it's not working" is hard to help with here @ShubhamVerma. First of all: after reading my answer, is it clear that the way you try to query an subset of an array doesn't work? And how putting the data in a map **could** solve that problem? If so, and you can't get it to work, add how you implemented it at the bottom of your question, so I can have a look.

Comment: I can't change the structure of the database, because it's already implemented. We need to find a solution based on the implemented structure. Please help me with the same if you can. Thanks :)

Comment: Firestore doesn't support querying an item in an array, so if you can't change your data structure to meet your needs you won't be able to implement the use-case.